# How can I see the changes to my string? What is wrong with the current method?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to reverse the words in a string and here is the following code. the print statement returns the same string but it should be "landed has eagle the"

Instead of void methods, I tried a different approach to the problem by returning strings and character arrays to reverseWords method and reverseCharacters method respectively. The output is even worse, it is giving me the address of something like "C@123433".

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the program?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    String string= "The eagle has landed";
   // char[]m =string.toCharArray();
    reverseWords(string.toCharArray());

    System.out.println(string);
}

public static void reverseWords(char[] message) {

    // first we reverse all the characters in the entire message array
    // this gives us the right word order
    // but with each word backwards
    reverseCharacters(message, 0, message.length - 1);

    // now we'll make the words forward again
    // by reversing each word's characters

    // we hold the index of the *start* of the current word
    // as we look for the *end* of the current word
    int currentWordStartIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= message.length; i++) {

        // found the end of the current word!
        if (i == message.length || message[i] == ' ') {

            // if we haven't exhausted the array, our
            // next word's start is one character ahead
            reverseCharacters(message, currentWordStartIndex, i - 1);
            currentWordStartIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}

private static void reverseCharacters(char[] message, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {

    // walk towards the middle, from both sides
    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {

        // swap the left char and right char
        char temp = message[leftIndex];
        message[leftIndex] = message[rightIndex];
        message[rightIndex] = temp;
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex--;
    }
}}
```

Comment: I copied your code, paste on a Java class file, compiled and ran it and it printed : "The eagle has landed"

Comment: `string.toCharArray()` returns a *copy* of the string's underlying array; changing it does nothing to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You need create a new String.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string= "The eagle has landed";
    char[] m =string.toCharArray(); // get the char[]
    reverseWords(m); // reverse char[]
    string = new String(m); // create a new String and let string refer it 
    System.out.println(string); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the reference of a char array, and then you lose it. The variable `string` is never modified.

There are other ways to do this, but this simple change in your main should work:

```
char[] m = string.toCharArray();
reverseWords(m);
System.out.println(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.
Just like this,create a new String to store the result and return it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
        String string= "The eagle has landed";
        // char[]m =string.toCharArray();
        String reverseWords = reverseWords(string.toCharArray());

        System.out.println(reverseWords);
    }

    public static String reverseWords(char[] message) {

        // first we reverse all the characters in the entire message array
        // this gives us the right word order
        // but with each word backwards
        reverseCharacters(message, 0, message.length - 1);

        // now we'll make the words forward again
        // by reversing each word's characters

        // we hold the index of the *start* of the current word
        // as we look for the *end* of the current word
        int currentWordStartIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= message.length; i++) {

            // found the end of the current word!
            if (i == message.length || message[i] == ' ') {

                // if we haven't exhausted the array, our
                // next word's start is one character ahead
                reverseCharacters(message, currentWordStartIndex, i - 1);
                currentWordStartIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }

        return new String(message);
    }

    private static void reverseCharacters(char[] message, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {

        // walk towards the middle, from both sides
        while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {

            // swap the left char and right char
            char temp = message[leftIndex];
            message[leftIndex] = message[rightIndex];
            message[rightIndex] = temp;
            leftIndex++;
            rightIndex--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse words order in string, you can try this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Collections;

....

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString= "The eagle has landed";

    // split words by space
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(myString.split("\\s"));

    // reverse words order
    Collections.reverse(myList);    

    // combine reverse words by space
    String reverseString = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(reverseString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing seriously wrong what you've done.

**Strings are constant**; their values cannot be changed after they are created. (AS said by cba Alpha).
You can assign it with a new String object.

When you use the below method, the string constant changes nothing. So printing the string object give the same with no change.

```
reverseWords(string.toCharArray());
```

Change your method

```
public static char[] reverseWords(char[] message) {
...
return message;
}
```

OR

```
public static String reverseWords(char[] message) {
...
return new String(message);
}
```

To print

```
System.out.println(reverseWords(string.toCharArray()));
```

You could have used pretty simple approach using utils classes. I think i don't need to explain it. You can find it in answers here, so it will be easy for you to simplify the code.